# Use a base class method as a decorator in derived classes

Tags: python

I have come across a situation where I have a base class and multiple derived classes. In each of the derived classes I am doing an action of extracting common data from input given to method. Thus I have written that piece of code in base class as method so that derived classes could use it directly. But I want to call this function from each method where I want to perform this action. My question is that can I write a decorator for this action? I want this decorator to be a member of base class. **Is it possible to use base class method as a decorator in derived classes?**

Comment: Can you provide an example of these methods? I don't see a difference between applying a decorator to each derived-class method and simply invoking the base-class method (via `super` or directly via the class name) inside the derived-class method.

Comment: There are multiple request handlers for various internal APIs. All these handlers have methods that call these APIs. Each of these internal APIs require request header which is part of incoming request. So in each method I have to extract this information from incoming request to form header required to call API. Thus to avoid repetition of code, I have created a base class and written this code in base class method. But now I want to use this base class method as a decorator in derived classes. How do I do that? Please let me know if you require further details.

Comment: Calling the base-class method from inside the derived-class method is no more repetitive than having to apply a decorator to each derived class method, and is easier to implement and read as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I also want to format the response to be sent by these handlers so I was planning to do header formation and  response generation in one place.

Comment: Again, this would be much clearer if you actually posted some sample code. It is of course possible to use a base-class method as a decorator, since a decorator is just a function which takes a function as input and returns another function. (The decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for rebinding the name of the input function to the output of the decorator.)

Answer (score 1):

Base class:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.request=None
        self.response=None

    def extractheader(self,requestin):
        ##extracts header from incoming request
```

Derived class:

```
class DerivedRequestHandler1(BaseRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DerivedRequestHandler1, self).__init__()  

    def handlermethod(self,requestin)
        ##extract headed
        ##call internal API with header
```